# ebay-api: GetOrders is missing some transactions

Tags: php, ebay-api

I have a problem with missing orders. When I call GetSellerTransactions I get all orders. When I call GetOrders with the same request (only the root-node's name is different), some of the (valid!) Orders are missing. I am aware of [this](https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1468/~/getorders-does-not-return-all-transactions). My rev is 801. I Tried this with various revisions > 705.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>[...]</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <ErrorLanguage>de_DE</ErrorLanguage>
    <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
    <ModTimeFrom>2012-12-06T09:00:00+01:00</ModTimeFrom>
    <ModTimeTo>2012-12-06T12:00:00+01:00</ModTimeTo>
    <Pagination>
        <EntriesPerPage>50</EntriesPerPage>
        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
    </Pagination>
</GetOrdersRequest>
```

Is there some spell to cast to get all orders (transactions) via GetOrders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you also aware, that **GetOrders** also returns only **100 orders in one call** and that you have to use the **pagination attribute** correctly, as described here: [Ebay GetOrders API call does not return orders as per the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800096/ebay-getorders-api-call-does-not-return-orders-as-per-the-request/11156684)

Comment: I do the very same steps to receive all orders with GetOrders as I did with GetSellerTransactions. I also get hundreds of orders with both calls. But when I use GetOrders, the Result is missing about 10% of the orders, GetSellerTransactions gave me. As I said above, I have a working importer at rev 445 (works since 2008).

Comment: We have a large shop working since 2009 an yet had no problems with GetOrders. We have configured this call so that it returns all completed orders with a modification date of the last 5 days. This seems to me a good practice, because until today we haven't lost an order. The only orders that wo do not receive are orders where you can see on the ebay site that the seller has paid but not completed the checkout. But that happens rarely and seems to be a problem on the ebay site.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `OrderStatus` field in your xml, you should pass this value either on `Active` and `Completed` to retrieve paid order (completed) as well as not paid (active) orders.

You can check on ebay documentation here:

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/GetOrders.html

I would also add to request `OrderRole` field set to Seller (so you can filter purchased from sold items)

To my experience i felt more confortable using `NumberOfDays` instead of `ModTime` filters wich doesn't make me deal with date/time format at all.

I hope this can help.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The XML above was just the simplest case. If you apply more filters like OrderRole or OrderStatus, you would only possibly reduce the number of results you get. But with no filters applied, I also did not receive all orders, GetSellerTransactions has returned. We have a working order-importer working with rev 445. Fairly old and working with GetSellerTrasactions is not the correct way today. The NumberOfDays parameter is not applicable to me, because I need to receive all new Orders every 15 Minutes (we have hundreds of orders a day and must react quickly).

Comment: Are you sure this 445 versions still works correctly? i was using AddMemberMessageAAQToPartner call yesterday and i noticed response was using version 803

Answer (score 0):

It's been some time since I asked this question, so I give a little Update.

Nowadays, the call works as "expected". May be I was on a broken revision or something, but the very same code as back in 2012 now works (checked it out from a version control system and tested again) - with the same revision number, but different orders.

I randomy mark another answer as "correct".