# Experiencing random issue with eBay Trading API, GetOrders call, and Excel VBA Script

Tags: ebay-api

First, I do not know if this is an issue with eBay's API or perhaps an issue with the way Microsoft Excel handles eBays XML response.  With that in mind, here's our issue:

On a daily basis, at 12:01AM Pacific Time, we use an Excel VBA script to instantiate a call to eBays Trading API, GetOrders method.  Upon retrieving an XML response (which contains the previous 5 days order data), we run additional VBA modules in Excel to transform the order data to our desired format.  This script has worked flawlessly for years. However, as of 04/14/2023, there are days when we are able to retrieve all orders, days when we only retrieve a few orders, and days when we retrieve zero orders.  Moreover, our result set rarely matches what we see in our online eBay Seller Hub.

Starting with the call to eBay, here's our code (which has not changed in years):

Here is the request header:

```
    X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL:756
    X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME:OUR_DEV_NAME
    X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME:OUR_APP_NAME
    X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME:OUR_CERT_NAME
    X-EBAY-API-SITEID:0
    X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME:GetOrders
```

Here is the request body:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>OUR_TOKEN</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <NumberOfDays>5</NumberOfDays>
    <OrderRole>Seller</OrderRole>
    <Pagination><EntriesPerPage>100</EntriesPerPage><PageNumber>1</PageNumber></Pagination>
    <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
    </GetOrdersRequest>
```

Is anyone else experiencing similar issues, and have you been able to resolve those issues?

Things we've tried or reviewed:

1. Updating our User Token, as mentioned here - https://community.ebay.com/t5/Traditional-APIs-Orders/Calls-to-API-no-longer-return-anything/m-p/33721560#M64, was already done.
2. Setting pagination, as mentioned here - [eBay API GetOrders call not returning all orders as requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800096/ebay-api-getorders-call-not-returning-all-orders-as-requested), was already configured in our script.